# MOst efficient way to draw line graph based on shaders

Tags: opengl, shader

I need to draw line graph with more than one million points, which will looks like this:

[image: example]

So I'm looking for the most efficient way to achieve this. After days of brainstorming, we decided to go with shaders because it utilizes GPU and should be performant enough to show my graph with millions of point with 20+ fps.

To eliminate problems with geometry during visualization, I guess shader should looks like this:

[image: shader geometry]

So, is it right direction I'm looking or there are more efficient ways exist?

Comment: On which display device do you intend to draw such a line _with more than one million points_?

Comment: @Armali it is for one FullHD screen and up to 3 monitors with 4K resolution. It depends on which hardware my client uses, but we have to consider maximum requirement as 3 screens with 4K.

Comment: Even for a screen length around 10000 pixels, I don't see how it makes sense to use more than one million points for one _line_.

Comment: @Armali it's maybe seems wasteful, but it's not always straightforward to simplify your dataset (depending on the change frequency, plus if you want to accurately zoom you might still need all the points). And a modern gpu can easily eat that geometry nowadays